# How to open Administrator mode?

Tags: c#

I want to open Administrator mode automatically after installing my application.

And also i want to add Font automatically into Client's PC when installing my application.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean "open Administrator mode in C# .Net". Related to your query on installing Font, you can make use of an Installer Tool like Installscript, Wix for packaging your application and Font.

Comment: And please, ask one question at a time.

Comment: My application need "Run as Administrator" mode to run correctly.
you know.we had "Run as Administrator" in Windows 7.
i mean like that.When installed my application,i do manually change Run as Administrator mode in property.i don't want to do this.It can automatically do in C#.Net..That is i want to know

Comment: why does your app need to run elevated?

Comment: Do you want to open in admin mode from the installation package itself or by running the application from a short-cut? Also, what are you using to install the application?

Answer (score 2):

if you need to configure your .NET application to always run in administrator mode after it has been installed, have a look at this:

[Run .NET Programs as Administrator on Vista or Windows 7](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VistaRunAsAdmin.aspx)

this only applies to Vista and Windows 7 and Win Server 2008 because in Windows XP if current user is administrator, application already runs in admin mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an application manifest requesting admin priviliges.
This begs the question of why it needs admin access as this is normally indicative of an incorrectly designed application.